# Score/Answer, for any tag badge explanation

Tags: support, tag-badges

I am an active answerer in the Swift, iOS, and Swift4 tags.

I am trying to get a badge of one of those, currently sitting on Swift tag with those stats:

> 19/100 score
>
> 39/20 answers

I have 800+ total reputation points and at least a 100 earned from the Swift tag, but those stats seems to be never updated. Am I missing something?

How do I achieve this? I already see the part (non-Community Wiki) and the questions are not community wiki or the answers, so what is the explanation?

Comment: "score" counts the number of votes, not the reputation which is a factor of 10 larger than the number of votes. If you earned 100 reputation, this increases the score by 10.

Comment: that explained a lot, Cheers